# How to set Content Mode for a UIImage in a UIButton as in UIImageView?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a function that creates an image (createPatchImage). I set its contentMode in the function because when I display the app on an iPad the image looked to stretched. Hence the set content mode which solves the issue.

On top of this image I have a UIButton, which background is also an image( UIImage). Is there a way I can set the content Mode for that image inside my UIButton? At this point the image is a UIImage, not a UIImageView.

The PatchImage's ratio looks great, now I just need to get the ratio for my button right. Does anyone know how to set the content mode for an image inside a button?

```
//Patch Image
func createPatchImage() {

    patch.image = UIImage(named: "leather-button-1x")
    patch.frame = CGRect(x: 57 / 320 * view.frame.width, y: 183 / 568 * view.frame.height, width: 210 / 320 * view.frame.width, height: 210 / 568 * view.frame.height)
    patch.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit

    self.view.addSubview(patch)
}







//UIButton with an image
 func createWaterDropButton() {

    waterDropButton.frame = CGRectMake(80 / 320 * view.frame.width, 204 / 568 * view.frame.height, 160 / 320 * view.frame.width, 160 / 568 * view.frame.height)
    if let waterDropImage  = UIImage(named: "drop-button-1x") {
        waterDropButton.setImage(waterDropImage, forState: .Normal)

    }

    waterDropButton.addTarget(self, action: "waterDropPressed:", forControlEvents:.TouchDown)
    self.view.addSubview(waterDropButton)
}
```